# A non-prepared query using MySQLi and Zend_DB

Tags: php, zend-framework, mysqli

Due to a bug in my servers PDO version, I have switched to using MySQLi. However, this presents another problem, as the [Zend_DB](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html) [MySQLi adaptor](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html#zend.db.adapter.adapter-notes.mysqli) doesn't have an exec function. (The [Zend PDO adaptor did](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html#zend.db.adapter.other-statements)), which means I can't execute a sql script. (Containing a load of DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE queries).

So where I could just do:

```
$sqlQuery = file_get_contents('schema.sql');
$db = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();
$db->exec($sqlQuery);
```

I can't find a way to do this using the Zend MySQLi Adaptor. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$sqlQuery = file_get_contents('schema.sql');
$adapter = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();
$mysqli = $adapter->getConnection(); // i think the returns the Mysqli Instance directly...
$mysqli->multi_query($sqlQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did

```
$bootstrap = $application->getBootstrap();
$bootstrap->bootstrap(‘db’);
$config = $bootstrap->getResource(‘db’)->getConfig();
$runCommand = “mysql -h “.$config["host"].” -P “.$config["port"].” -u’”.$config["username"].”‘ -p’”.$config["password"].”‘ “.$config["dbname"].” < “.dirname(__FILE__) . ‘/schema.mysql.sql’;
echo $runCommand;
system($runCommand);
```

More info: 
http://www.unexpectedit.com/zend-php/zend-db-exec-a-sql-file